# How to code Auto Loan calc with fixed months and interest? (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I need to make an auto loan calculator that is only able to calculate 2.3% interest for 84 months. I've never made a calculator that didn't allow a user to input these amounts, so how do I code that part of the calc?

Comment: it is the same as allowing them to enter the amounts. you just hard-code the values

Comment: How would this look in code though? I'm very new to VB.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim res As Decimal = 100 ' Current value
    Dim interest As Decimal = 1.89 / 100 ' 1.89%
    For i As Integer = 1 To 89 'Months
        Dim amr As Decimal = res * interest
        res += amr
    Next
    MsgBox(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to calculate.. Monthly paiement, equity, what is left to pay ?

Here's the formula to calculate the monthly paiement of a loan

```
    Dim monthlyPaiement As Decimal
    Dim loanAmount As Decimal
    Dim interestRate As Decimal
    Dim loanLengthInMonth As Decimal

    loanAmount = 25000
    interestRate = 1.9 / 100
    loanLengthInMonth = 84

    interestRate /= 12 ' Divide by number of month in a year
    monthlyPaiement = loanAmount * ((1 + interestRate) ^ loanLengthInMonth) * interestRate / (((1 + interestRate) ^ loanLengthInMonth) - 1)
```